# Use html data-* attributes on script element to configure referenced script file

Tags: javascript, html

In a HTML page, I want to use data-* attributes to configure scripts such as:

```
<script src="someOtherScript.js" data-target-element="elementId"></script>
```

Then, in the script file, what I would like to do is something along those lines:

```
(function() {
    var id = '' // Get the value of data-target-element here
    // [...Run some code that uses the id ...]
})
```

What I would like is for it to work on any page so I can declaratively configure scripts, a bit like this:

```
<script src="SomeWidget.js" data-target-element="element1"></script>
<script src="SomeWidget.js" data-target-element="element2"></script>
<script src="SomeWidget.js" data-target-element="element3"></script>
```

Comment: It seems like it would make more sense to declare an initialisation function which takes the ID of the target element as a parameter. That way you only load the script once, rather than multiple times, but can still tie each instance to a specific element.

Comment: Including the same script more than one time is not an issue. I guess I have to provide a bit more context. The data-* are to be used from server side technology such as asp.net mvc. data-* attributes would contain configuration data such as url for a web service or localized text to display.

Comment: Having dynamic javascript is harder from server-side technologies such as asp.net mvc than having dynamic html (Razor calls like `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` or using Resource files). Which is why I would like to be able to configure from the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want each widget type have it's own `data-widgetType` attribute something like:

```
<script src="SomeWidget.js" data-someWidget  data-target-element="element1"></script>
<script src="anotherWidget.js" data-anotherWidget data-target-element="element2"></script>
```

Then each widget script would look for it's own attribute. This seems backwards and not very dynamic though since you would then have to predetermine all the elements in advance on page that widget would manipulate if plan on using ID, or have to generate classes in your script tag and in markup.

It makes far more sense to put the `data-widgetType` in markup for elements that script will act on. Then you are free to add or remove from html at will, and not have to keep track of any identifiers with your script tag.

Comment: You didn't answer the (IMO) more important question – how to get that attribute?

Comment: @Darkhogg  where was that asked? Question is not very specific about anything. Not hard to research that one

Comment: Well, OP in fact did not ask anything, but I assume that was his main concern.

Comment: @Darkhogg well your assumption and mine are different. I saw all the same attributes, so my assumption was how to tell them apart. Feel free to  provide different solution

Answer (score 0):

The following code only works, if your script is embedded directly in the HTML page without async/defer attributes.

```
var scripts = document.scripts || document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var me = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
var target = me.getAttribute('data-target-element');
```